# How can I use stat_smooth to show one line, on a two factor figure?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame as such:

```
df <- data.frame(a = runif(1000), b = runif(1000), c = runif(1000),  d = sample(c("yes", "no"), 1000, replace=TRUE))
```

And I ran a logistic regression:

```
lm <- glm(data = df, factor(d) ~ a + b + c, family = binomial)
```

Produced the predicted probabilities:

```
df$pred <- predict(lm, type = "response")
```

And would like to graph the result with both a jitter plot for `a` and `b`, a color fill for `d` and a smooth line (using geom_smooth) for simply the effect of `a` on `d`

I've tried this:

```
ggplot(data = df , aes(x=a, y = b, color = factor(d))) + geom_jitter() +
geom_smooth(data = df, aes(x=a, y = pred))
```

But it's not producing what I would like. What I would like is this line:

```
ggplot(data = df , aes(x=a, y = pred)) + geom_smooth()
```

overlaid on this:

```
ggplot(data = df , aes(x=a, y = b, color = factor(d))) + geom_jitter()
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding a line for `pred` vs. `a` to a plot of `b` vs. `a` doesn't make sense. It happens to "look" like it works in this case, because all of your predictor variables range between 0 and 1, the same range as `pred`, which is a probability, and therefore also ranges from 0 to 1. But you're superimposing apples on oranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the trick, now it doesn't group it per factor anymore:

```
  ggplot(data = df ) +  
  geom_point(aes(x=a, y = b, color = factor(d))) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=a, y = pred))
```

You now make a ggplot where you specify the data. On top of that you add a layer with points (a and b) and on top of that the geom smooth line.

But make sure that you also have a look at the y-axis of both plots. In your geom_smooth() plot you see the nice s-shape curve. However, the Y-axis range is from 0.51 to 0.47.

[image]

If we then look at your total plot with limits of 0 and 1. Your line looks almost straight which is just because of the limits. [image]

Comment: Looks great - and thanks... learned something new about ggplot today : )

Answer (score 2):

The [other solution (by MichaelVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30564261/) does not work for me. However, I've found how to solve it here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/smooths.htm

In short:

setting `aes(group = 1)` in `stat_smooth` (but legend has additional lines)

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, colour = factor(vs))) + geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)
```

or better - using factor fields only in `geom_point`, not `ggplot` (this thing has clean legend):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(vs))) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)
```